# How to quickly revert the buffer?

Tags: revert-buffer

`revert-buffer` is often slower than closing an opening the same file.

I've noticed - for example, I can undo to the state of the file before reverting.

While this might be useful in some cases, I would like to clear undo history and load the file as if I'd just opened emacs.

Some possible solutions:

**Fast Revert**

- Disable undo.
- Clear undo history, jump list ... etc.
- Clear the buffer.
- Load the data from the file into the buffer.
- Re-enable undo.

**Fake Revert**

- Store the scroll & cursor position.
- Close the buffer.
- Open the buffer.
- Restore the scroll & cursor position.

While I could write this, it seems like there may be a more elegant solution then writing my own `fast-revert-buffer` function.

Does Emacs provide a way to do this already?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in terms of `undo`, the previous history would be irrelevant -- as such, the undo history would be completely reset to zero / nil upon a revert.

Comment: Just a question: does using `global-auto-revert-mode` with `auto-revert-interval` set to a small value (I set it at `1`) help?

Comment: Id rather keep reverting to be a manual operation.

Comment: @lawlist the undo history is kept (using emacs undo - no wrappers)

Answer (score 2):

The `revert-buffer` function takes a few parameters which I think make the reload faster. I've got this bound to a keyboard shortcut for reloading the current buffer, it feels as fast as when you first open the file:

```el
(defun reload-file-preserve-point ()
  (interactive)
  (when (or (not (buffer-modified-p))
            (y-or-n-p "Reverting will discard changes. Proceed?"))
    (save-excursion
      (revert-buffer t t t))
    (setq buffer-undo-list nil)
    (message "Buffer reverted")))
```

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE and thank you for your answer!  Maybe you could briefly describe what the args do that make the revert faster (this is something I immediately think I want to know when I read the answer).